# Customize welcome message after registration

Tags: magento2, registration, customer-registration

I need to customize the message that is presented to the customer after his registration. 
I do not need to change only the message, but I need to show a different text if the user has checked a field in the registration form.

Comment: I think you need to override this controller `vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Observer** here like

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost">
        <observer name="customer_account_create_post" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CreatePost" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/CreatePost.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class CreatePost implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $messageManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $condition = 'Your condition';

        if($condition){
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __("Custom message here!")
            );
        }

        return $observer;
    }  
}
```

Hope this is helful to you!